# Using GitLab CI/CD with Docker Hub

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, dockerhub

We're trying to use Docker Hub to store the images generated, and used, by our GitLab CI/CD builds, but are having some trouble getting it to work properly.

I've been successful in pushing the image built in the `build` stage to Docker Hub, that works fine, what doesn't work is trying to pull it down again for the `rspec` stage. I get the following error:

> ERROR: Job failed: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for foxsoft/zzz, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied (executor_docker.go:192:1s)

I'm going to assume it has something to do with my login credentials not being picked up correctly when trying to pull the image down, but I'm not sure. Any help you can provide will be appreciated.

Here's my config:

```
before_script:
  - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD"

.ruby_base:
  image: ruby:2.5.5
  before_script:
    - ruby -v

.docker_base:
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:stable-dind
    - postgres:9.6
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  before_script:
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD

stages:
  - build
  - test

build:images:
  extends: .docker_base
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker build -t $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE .
    - docker push $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE

test:rspec:
  before_script:
    - echo $CONTAINER_TEST_IMAGE
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD
  image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  stage: test
  services:
    - postgres:9.6
  variables:
    POSTGRES_DB: zzz_test
    DB_HOST: postgres
  script:
    - bundle exec rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rake db:schema:load RAILS_ENV=test
    - bundle exec rspec --format html --out rspec/index.html --format documentation
```

I've also set the following environment variables

`CI_REGISTRY_USER` my docker hub username
`CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD` my docker hub token
`CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` is set to `foxsoft/zzz` (which is hosted [here](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/foxsoft/zzz) - although as a private repo, you won't be able to see it)

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using `protected variable` on Gitlab CI/CD variable?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue (I think) by creating a `DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG` variable within the CI/CD settings, and set it to the following:

```
{
   "auths":{
      "index.docker.io":{
         "auth":"HASHED_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD"
      }
   }
}
```

The `HASHED_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD` value was generated by running the following command on my local machine:

```
echo -n "docker_hub_username:docker_hub_security_token" | base64
```

Comment: Be careful, `base64` is *not* a hash, just an encoding. Given your `base64`-encoded string, one can trivially retrieve your username/password combination. You would only have to assume an initial source encoding, but ASCII/UTF-8 (same thing in this case) will be a safe bet here.

Comment: I think this is just how it needs to be configured for it to work. Thankfully, the value is set to an environment variable, so it's not publicly accessible anyway.